# Cartesian coordinates in Houghlines

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, polar-coordinates, houghlines

Why can't we use Cartesian coordinates(x,y) instead of polar coordinates(r,theta) in Houghlines transformations ? Can any one clarify?

Comment: because it is more efficient? Maybe they should add a converter though :)

Comment: How would you paraneterize a line using Cartesian coordinates? The “Hough space” is the parameter space, a space spanned by the parameters of the shape you want to detect.

Comment: Basically because the HoughLines transform was designed that way, and it wouldn't make sense to have them in cartessian (the whole idea is to encode or parametrize straight lines comprised of many pixels into just 2 variables rho and theta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand (quoted from wikipedia):

The simplest case of Hough transform is detecting straight lines. In general, the straight line `y = mx + b` can be represented as a point `(b, m)` in the parameter space. However, vertical lines pose a problem. They would give rise to unbounded values of the slope parameter `m`. Thus, for computational reasons, Duda and Hart proposed the use of the Hesse normal form `r = x*cos(theta) + y*sin(theta)`, where `r` is the distance from the origin to the closest point on the straight line, and `theta` is the angle between the `x` axis and the line connecting the origin with that closest point.

A line can be detected by finding the number of intersections between curves.The more curves intersecting means that the line represented by that intersection have more points. In general, we can define a threshold of the minimum number of intersections needed to detect a line.
This is what the Hough Line Transform does. It keeps track of the intersection between curves of every point in the image. If the number of intersections is above some threshold, then it declares it as a line with the parameters `(theta,r_(theta))` of the intersection point. (OpenCV docs)